# Remove new line from the end of string SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database table called Players with almost 400 rows. I'm using *sqlite* under *DB Browser for SQLite*.

All of my TEXT fields have a "\n" added at the end of my string.

Ex:

```
"Louie
"
```

I tried RTRIM to get rid of the white spaces, but it didn't work.

How can I get from

```
"Louie
"
```

to

```
"Louie"
```

?

Comment: Please do not change your question after is has been answered correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `replace` function. For example:

```
Select replace(<ColumnName>, CHAR(10), '') from <table_name>;
```

Here, `CHAR(10)` is for newline character `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `REPLACE` function. replace new line character with null.